# How to add DateTimeField in django without microsecond

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing django application in django 1.8 and mysql 5.7.

Below is the model which I have written:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "people"
```

Above model creates the table below:

```
mysql> desc people;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| age         | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| create_time | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here Django creates datetime field with microsecond

> datetime(6)

But I want datetime field without microsecond

> datetime

I have another application, which is also using the same database and that datetime field with microsecond is raising an issue for me.

Comment: Check this link...might help you....[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368290/django-datetimefield-and-timezone-now).

Comment: Are you sure you need `DATETIME` format in MySQL? Judging by the name of the attribute `create_time`, you'd probably need `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. If you want to save automatically the creation time you can change your statement to: `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`.

Comment: @cezar `auto_now_add` store data with milliseconds. He doesn't want to store this time in his database.

Comment: I think timestamp also coming with fraction. my issue is fraction. I used other tool called dbslayer which fetch datetime field as string because of fraction instead of datetime object.

Comment: Indeed, Django creates `datetime` out of `DateTimeField` (which sounds logically). I have checked my code with MySQL 5.5 and there it is just `datetime`. Probably it is since MySQL 5.7 that this field is saved as `datetime(6)`.

Comment: There is any setting available in django models which provide us to set fraction setting ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really very interesting question. I looked through the source code and here is the reason for setting the `datetime` with fractional seconds. The following snippet is from the file `django/db/backends/mysql/base.py`:

```
class DatabaseWrapper(BaseDatabaseWrapper):
    vendor = 'mysql'
    # This dictionary maps Field objects to their associated MySQL column
    # types, as strings. Column-type strings can contain format strings; they'll
    # be interpolated against the values of Field.__dict__ before being output.
    # If a column type is set to None, it won't be included in the output.
    _data_types = {
        'AutoField': 'integer AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'BinaryField': 'longblob',
        'BooleanField': 'bool',
        'CharField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        'CommaSeparatedIntegerField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        'DateField': 'date',
        'DateTimeField': 'datetime',
        'DecimalField': 'numeric(%(max_digits)s, %(decimal_places)s)',
        'DurationField': 'bigint',
        'FileField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        'FilePathField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        'FloatField': 'double precision',
        'IntegerField': 'integer',
        'BigIntegerField': 'bigint',
        'IPAddressField': 'char(15)',
        'GenericIPAddressField': 'char(39)',
        'NullBooleanField': 'bool',
        'OneToOneField': 'integer',
        'PositiveIntegerField': 'integer UNSIGNED',
        'PositiveSmallIntegerField': 'smallint UNSIGNED',
        'SlugField': 'varchar(%(max_length)s)',
        'SmallIntegerField': 'smallint',
        'TextField': 'longtext',
        'TimeField': 'time',
        'UUIDField': 'char(32)',
    }

    @cached_property
    def data_types(self):
        if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
            return dict(self._data_types, DateTimeField='datetime(6)', TimeField='time(6)')
        else:
            return self._data_types

    # ... further class methods
```

In the method `data_types` the if condition checks the MySQL version. The method `supports_microsecond_precision` comes from the file `django/db/backends/mysql/features.py`:

```
class DatabaseFeatures(BaseDatabaseFeatures):
    # ... properties and methods

    def supports_microsecond_precision(self):                                         
        # See https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/issues/24 for the reason          
        # about requiring MySQLdb 1.2.5                                               
        return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
```

So when you use MySQL 5.6.4 or higher the field `DateTimeField` is mapped to `datetime(6)`.

I couldn't find any possibility given by Django to adjust this, so ended up with monkey patching:

```
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper

DatabaseWrapper.data_types = DatabaseWrapper._data_types
```

Put the above code where it suits best your needs, be it `models.py` or `__init__.py`, or maybe some other file.
When running migrations Django will create column `datetime` and not `datetime(6)` for `DateTimeField`, even if you're using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: this one looks like a global change of DateTimeField in the entire app. Is there something that allows us to change the fraction for just several tables instead of all tables?

Comment: @GodBlessYou Your assumption is right, this is a global change in the entire app. I have to think about your question, if it is possible to achieve this per model i.e. table.

Comment: Just saw my other answer. I completely forgot it. That can help you with your requirement to change it per table.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320118/model-field-added-using-custom-sql-not-detected-by-django) gave me an idea. What if you try to manually change the migrations.
First run `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that edit the file `0001_initial.py` (or whatever the name is) in the subdirectory `migrations` of your app:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name = 'People'
            fields = [
                # the fields
                # ... in this part comment or delete create_time
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE people ADD COLUMN create_time datetime(0)",
            reverse_sql="ALTER TABLE people DROP COLUMN create_time",
            state_operations=[
                migrations.AddField(
                    model_name='people',
                    name='create_time',
                    fields= models.DateTimeField(),
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
```

This is just an example. You can try with different options and check with:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrations yourapp 0001
```

what the SQL output is. Instead of yourapp and 0001 provide the name of your app and the number of the migration.

Here is a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html) to the official documentation about fractional seconds time values.

EDIT: I tested the code above with MySQL 5.7 and it works as expected. Maybe it can help someone else. If you get some errors, check that you have installed `mysqlclient` and `sqlparse`.

Comment: It is good when we have less no of table. But Writing custom migration for large no of tables it's not good idea.

Comment: In your question you didn't mention any number of tables. There is only one model class and respectively one table. The answer takes into account only those requirements.

Comment: How many tables do you have? Do all of them have the same field `create_time`?

Comment: I have near 230 tables in application. In which may 60 to 70 table with datetime field with different field name.

Comment: Above one I created temporary to explain my question it's not part of my application.