# How do I force Django's DateTimeField to always use microseconds

Tags: python, django

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539755/how-to-add-datetimefield-in-django-without-microsecond) answer helped me quite a bit, but I am trying to go for something different, and wondering if there is an easy way to do it.

I have some data that always needs to have microsecond precision.  Currently, I'm just storing it as a `BigIntegerField` and converting it when needed.  However, I would like to store it as a `DateTimeField` or something similar so I don't have to litter the code with converters.

I know Django will preserve this information on our production database, but our tests run using the SQLite DB. It's one of those edge cases, where it shouldn't matter, but I want to try to future-proof the application a bit.

Does anyone know if Django has a fallback method or if its fallback is just to throw away the extra information when using databases that don't support that level of precision?

Edit: It looks like the latest version of SQLite does support the extra precision.

Comment: Django just throws away precision that is not supported by the underlying database type.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It's understandable, but seems like a solvable problem.  The thing about ORMs is the consumer really shouldn't care about what the underlying data structure looks like.

Comment: In general, ORMs abstract away the underlying DB, but some things cannot be solved. Your case is a good example. I always advise to use the exact same db for testing than for production. There's really no reason to use sqlite if you're using something else in production.

Comment: Everything is a cost tradeoff.  For me, the ability of swapping out different SQLite databases or just copying a file then doing something dangerous and restoring it is a godsend in development.  The time saving vastly outweigh the differences between dev and prod.  Plus, there's the whole testing / QA stage which is running on the same DB type as prod.